# Dense rank, partitioned by column A, incremented by change in column B but ordered by column C

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, gaps-and-islands

I have a table like so

```
name|subtitle|date
ABC|excel|2018-07-07
ABC|excel|2018-08-08
ABC|ppt|2018-09-09
ABC|ppt|2018-10-10
ABC|excel|2018-11-11
ABC|ppt|2018-12-12
DEF|ppt|2018-12-31
```

I want to add a column that increments whenever there's a change in the subtitle, like so:

```
name|subtitle|date|Group_Number
ABC|excel|2018-07-07|1
ABC|excel|2018-08-08|1
ABC|ppt|2018-09-09|2
ABC|ppt|2018-10-10|2
ABC|excel|2018-11-11|3
ABC|ppt|2018-12-12|4
DEF|ppt|2018-12-31|1
```

the problem is if I do Dense_rank() over(partition by name order by subtitle) then not only will this group all subtitles into one group but it also remove the date ordering. I've also tried using the lag function but that doesn't seem to be very useful when you're trying to increment a column.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Bear in mind that the table I'm using has hundreds of different names.

Comment: There's no date ordering unless you specify it with an `ORDER BY` clause. What did you try, what did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: You first need to do "islands and gaps" to work out which group of rows each e.g. `excel` row belongs to, then you can partition by name and island.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick answer**

```
declare @table table (name varchar(20),subtitle varchar(20),[date] date )

insert into @table (name,subtitle,date)
values
('ABC','excel','2018-07-07'),
('ABC','excel','2018-08-08'),
('ABC','ppt','2018-09-09'),
('ABC','ppt','2018-10-10'),
('ABC','excel','2018-11-11'),
('ABC','ppt','2018-12-12'),
('DEF','ppt','2018-12-31');

with nums as (

    select *,  
         case when subtitle != lag(subtitle,1) over (partition by name order by date) 
              then 1 
              else 0 end as num
    from @table
)
select *,
    1+sum(num) over (partition by name order by date) AS Group_Number
from nums
```

**Explanation**

What you ask isn't exactly ranking. You are trying to [detect "islands"](https://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions) where the name and subtitle are the same in a sequences ordered strictly by the date.

To do that, you can compare the current row's value to the previous one. If they match, you are in the same "island". If not, there's a switch. You can use that to emit eg `1` each time a change is detected.

That's what:

```
CASE WHEN subtitle != LAG(subtitle,1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date) 
     THEN 1
```

Once you have that, you can calculate the number of changes with a running total :

```
sum(num) over (partition by name order by date) AS Group_Number
```

This will generate values starting from 0. To get numbers starting from 1, just add 1:

```
1+sum(num) over (partition by name order by date) AS Group_Number
```

**UPDATE**

As T. Clausen explains in the comments, reversing the comparison will get rid of the `+1` :

```
with nums as (

    select *,  
         case when subtitle = lag(subtitle,1) over (partition by name order by date) 
              then 0 
              else 1 end as num
    from @table
)
select *,
    sum(num) over (partition by name order by date) AS Group_Number
from nums
```

It's also a *better* way to detect islands, even if the results in this case are the same. The first query would produce this result :

```
name    subtitle    date    num Group_Number
ABC     excel   2018-07-07  0   1
ABC     excel   2018-08-08  0   1
ABC     ppt     2018-09-09  1   2
ABC     ppt     2018-10-10  0   2
ABC     excel   2018-11-11  1   3
ABC     ppt     2018-12-12  1   4
DEF     ppt     2018-12-31  0   1
```

The query emits `1` when a subtitle break is detected *except* at the boundaries.

The second query returns :

```
name    subtitle    date    num Group_Number
ABC     excel   2018-07-07  1   1
ABC     excel   2018-08-08  0   1
ABC     ppt     2018-09-09  1   2
ABC     ppt     2018-10-10  0   2
ABC     excel   2018-11-11  1   3
ABC     ppt     2018-12-12  1   4
DEF     ppt     2018-12-31  1   1
```

In this case `1` is emitted for each change, including the boundaries

Comment: you can simplify it a bit by using **subtitle =** instead of **!=** and reverse **then** and not adding 1 at the end(and make it shorter by using IF instead of case)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk you can't use `IF` in a `SELECT`. As for reversing, do you mean `when subtitle = lag(subtitle,1) ... then 0 else 1` ? That works, it's just that the inequality was the first thing I tried

Comment: @t-clausen.dk that's indeed better because it returns `1` in every island change

Comment: **iif(subtitle = lag(subtitle) over (partition by name order by date),0,1)** sorry was missing an F